# Why doesn't Python 2.6 have set literals and comprehensions or dict comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 2.6 was basically a stepping stone to make converting to Python 3 easier.  A lot of the features destined for Python 3 were implemented in 2.6 if they didn't break backward compatibility with syntax and the class libs.

Why weren't set literals (`{1, 2, 3}`), set comprehensions (`{v for v in l}`), or dict comprehensions (`{k: v for k, v in d}`) among them?  In particular dict comprehensions would have been a great boon... I find myself using the considerably uglier `dict([(k, v) for k, v in d])` an awful lot lately.

Is there something obvious I'm missing, or was this just a feature that didn't make the cut?

Comment: Note that all these features have been implemented in Python 2.7. http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It wasn't done because nobody took the time to do it. There are bugs opened for months, and no one commented on them:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue2333
- http://bugs.python.org/issue2334
- http://bugs.python.org/issue2335

So it wasn't important enough for anybody to care, probably.

Comment: Your answer is more concise and helpful than mine :)

Answer (score 10):

All these are syntax/grammar changes. Such changes are traditionally introduced first in a Python x.y version with a `from __future__ import …` statement, and implemented at least on Python x.(y+1) version. Such a transition hasn't happened yet for these changes.

Technically, I've answered your "why".

Now, if you meant, “why didn't anyone take the time to suggest, support and implement something that *I* would like to have in 2.x also, even if *they* don't know about it since *I* never tried to suggest/support backporting those syntax enhancements in either comp.lang.python or Python-Dev and *I* never tried to even read the PEPs?”, then the answer lies in you too, and you can offer an answer yourself.

HTH

BTW, you shouldn't use the `dict([(k,v) for k,v in d])` form, but the `dict((k,v) for k,v in d)`. More efficient. Why create an intermediate list?